# iPad Mini / 9.7 - Sharepoint Online / Safari & IOS App Site scaling

Tags: app, promoted-links, online

I have created a SharePoint site on SharePoint Online. This site holds a Document library (Around 15 documents here) along with 8 lists for data to be entered into columns.

Promoted links have been set up to each one of these document templates in the library and to each one of the lists created.

These promoted links have then been embedded as tiles on the Home page as a webpart.

When looking at the site on on a PC browser the site looks fine and works well. When looking at the site on an iPad Mini / 9.7 display via the App or Safari everything (Mainly the promoted link webparts) doesn't scale correctly and starts clipping.

Is there anyway to have this scale 1:1 on the app or safari on these devices and allow users to use the pinch feature should then need to zoom?

Please see the attached examples below:

Ipad:

Comment: can you add the below line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />` inside the `<head>` tag of master page and check ?

Comment: I tried adding this to the v4.master page - didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

We have applied following styles which work perfect in browsers and all devices (Desktop, iPad, Tablet). See these might help you.

```
.ms-promlink-body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    float: left;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Desktop:**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]